# Why will Java convert the double to float type in this situation?

Tags: java, eclipse

Today, I defined two float variable ***f1*** and ***f2***. Then I perform an addition, "+", arithmetic operation and assign to float variable ***f***.

```
float f1 = 0.5048076923076923F;
float f2 = 0.5048076923076923F;
float f = f1 + f2;
```

This is the output:
[image]

According to this picture, All floating point values (***float*** and ***double***) in an arithmetic operation (**+, −, *, /**) are converted to **double** type:
picture source: [http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html)
[image]

I found an identical question but it hasn't explain why. Why doesn't eclipse have any issue tips? Is it the reason why the value of ***"f1 + f2"*** is a float type? And, why will Java auto convert the double to float type if like the above picture saying?
[image: picture source: https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/short_float_variables.html]

Comment: The result of adding two `float`(s) is a `float`. As far as I know, `float`(s) are **not** widened to `double` before arithmetic. That assertion doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Might be he just copy-pasted a text for double and forgot to revise it.

Comment: Maybe my expression is not very clear, but Stephen C's answer has solved this problem. What I thought before was that two floats would be converted to a double type. Thank you for your help. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be saying that there is a conversion to `float` in the following.

```
float f1 = 0.5048076923076923F;
float f2 = 0.5048076923076923F;
float f = f1 + f2;
```

In fact, there is no conversion.  The values are all `float`.

In particular, the literal `0.5048076923076923F` is a `float`.  The trailing `F` makes it a `float`.   If you want a double literal, leave off the `F` or replace it with `D`.

When your teacher says "all floating point values are converted to `double`" he is wrong.  The JLS says (in effect) that a numeric primitive operand will be converted to `double` *when the other operand is a `double`*.  If both operands are `float`, then the operation will performed using single-precision floating point arithmetic.

The JLS reference is [JLS 5.6.2: Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

---

It has been pointed out that there may be additional conversions happening at the hardware level. For example, the JLS says this:

> Within an expression that is not FP-strict, some leeway is granted for an implementation to use an extended exponent range to represent intermediate results; the net effect, roughly speaking, is that a calculation might produce "the correct answer" in situations where exclusive use of the float value set or double value set might result in overflow or underflow.

However:

- This is only allowed if the expression is not `strictfp`.
- These are not the "conversions" that the JLS talks about in JLS 5.6.2.
- This still contradicts what the OP's teacher is saying.  He (or she) states that the *all*  floating point calculations are done using `double`.  The JLS states that *under certain circumstances*, a hardware platform *may* use extended precision arithmetic (possibly with more precision than 64 bit floating point), and in other circumstances it *must not do this*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This answer solved my problem very well. I am going to tell my teacher. 

Answer (score 4):

Your teacher is incorrect, kindly refer him to [section 5.6.2 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), which states:

> - Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>   - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>   - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>   - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

As you can see, floats are only converted to double **if the other operand is a double**, not in all cases as your syllabus incorrectly states.

That is, the sum of two floats is a float, but the sum of a float and a double is a double.

PS: And no, Java will never convert a double to a float unless you explicitly ask it to, as in:

```
float f = (float) Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi for floating points values JVM uses instructions like this:

'+' : fadd : pops two floats, adds them, and pushes the float result
 '-' : fsub : pops two floats, subtracts them and pushes the flot result

similarly for there are other instructions set for other operators like * and / etc.

So as per JVM implementation point of view float + float will result to float. 
But float + double will result to double.

For more information, you can read chapter 14. Floating-Point Arithmetic
 of the book "Inside Java Virtual Machine"

Comment: *"So as per JVM implementation point of view float + float will result to float. But float + double will result to double."* ... is incorrect.  The JVM spec and implementation say nothing about what Java code means, or how a Java compiler should map the Java `+` operator to bytecodes.  They merely determine what the bytecodes mean.  Referring to books on the JVM won't help you understand Java semantics.  You need a book on Java.

Comment: (Likewise, referring to the instruction set spec for Intel x86-64 processor won't explain the semantics of the C programming language.)

Answer (score 0):

What the other answers are missing is the hardware level. Floating point processors, in general, convert all operations to double (or quad), and then return the result in the requested precision. The Java specification may not recognize the conversion, but if it uses the floating point hardware then the conversion happens.

Comment: .... unless you use `strictfp`.   Besides, those conversions are not what the JLS means when it uses the term "conversion".  And the fact remains that the OP's teacher is saying (with no qualification) that the computation is always performed using double arithmetic ... which in the light of what you say ... is wrong for **two** reasons.